# C Program: Get inode header fields and information by inode number

Tags: c++, c, shell, linux-kernel, inode

I need to write a program in C/C++ that request the user to put in an inode number and then return all of the inode header fields and information back. I am not familiar with linux systems and commands at all. I have found some commands and tried different things that didnt work like I needed.

```
find -inum inodenumber
```

will give me the path to the file that contains the specified number. All the information I need comes from istat (according to my research) but I cant get it to work. Im doing

```
istat FILENAME.jpg
```

I get the response:

Missing image name and/or address
usage: istat[-B num] [-f fstype] [-i ingtype] [-b dev_sector_size] [-o imgoffset] [-z zone] [-s seconds] [ivV] image inum ...

What do I need to do?

Comment: you can get the file's inode number with `ls -i file` or `stat --format %i file`

Answer (score 1):

[`istat`](http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/man/istat.html) only works on disk images, not live filesystems.

There are no system calls in Linux which can look a file up in a live filesystem by its inode number.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I wanted to get the following inode information (File owner identifier, File type, File access permissions, File access time, Number of links to the file, Table of contents, File size), what command do you suggest? Only thing I have come across is istate.

Comment: Find a path to the file and `stat` it. Or, hell, `ls -l`.

Comment: the requirements is to do it by the inode number (without a file name or path) I tried doing a combination of stat and with the inode number like:
    stat INODENUMBER
and no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Run [`man istat`](http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/man/istat.html) of course.

In general, you can always get help from the terminal itself by running `man`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `find` with the inode number and then use the filename it generates with `stat`.